# swapdepth actionscript 2

Tags: actionscript-2

I want bring to front movieclip on Press 
and bring to back movieclip on Release
from movieclip in just one layer

I use
this.swapDepths (depth)
does not work

code:

`this.onPress = function(){
this.swapDepths(100);enter code here
}
this.onRelease = function(){this.swapDepths(-100);}`

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use this:

```
this.onRelease = function() { 
    this.swapDepths(mc1);
}; 
this.onRelease = function() { 
    this.swapDepths(mc2); 
};
```

mc1 and mc2 are the instance names of the 2 movieclips.

use "this.mc1" / "this.mc2" if those movieclips are inside the button object.

That way, they simply trade Depths with each other without you knowing what depth each on has.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have this "char" object placed in the screen(not generated dynamically) and you have this "enemy" object attached with the following code :

```
var enemy = _root.attachMovie("enemyBmp","enemyBmp",1);
```

Now your problem is that "enemy" object appears in top of your "char" object.
What you need to do now is :

```
enemy.swapDepths(char);
```